# Custom UITableViewCell with UIButton: unable to change UIImage

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I have a custom `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCell` it contains an `UIButton` i want to change Background image of selected button when the user selects it,

Unfortunately, the image is not changing state whenever I press it and it shows:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView
>   setBackgroundImage:forState:]:

***Here is my code snippet:***

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BTSTicketsCellIdentifier";
    CRIndCategCell *cell = (CRIndCategCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        //Initialize cell
    }

    cell.favBtn.tag=indexPath.row;
    [cell.favBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(AddToFav:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

      ...
      ...
      ...

}

-(IBAction)AddToFav:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Value of selected button = %ld",(long)[sender tag]);

    UIButton *Btn=(UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:(long)[sender tag]];
    [Btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [Btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grey-star.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


}
```

**My Log shows Value of selected button correctly but unable to change image of button**

***Thank you for reading.***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to modify your `AddToFav:` method to:

```
-(IBAction)AddToFav:(UIButton *)sender{
    NSLog(@"Value of selected button = %ld",(long)[sender tag]);

    [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grey-star.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


}
```

Or use this:

```
-(IBAction)AddToFav:(UIButton *)sender{
    NSLog(@"Value of selected button = %ld",(long)[sender tag]);
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    for (UIButton *btn in [cell.contentView.superview subviews] ) {
        if ([btn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]&& btn.tag ==(long)[sender tag]) {
           [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grey-star.png"]       
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if button's tag == 0. This is default tag for contentView of UITableViewCell and it's possible that you are trying to change image of cell's contentView.